# Receive all the push notifications when devices are offline

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm creating an iOS and Android native app, using Firebase for sending push notifications.

It's working fine, but when I switch off my devices and send some notifications, after starting the devices, I just receive the last one sent for iOS, and the same for Android.

Is there a way to receive all the push notifications even when the devices are offline and they're started?

Comment: I also have problem like you. Turn off Wi-Fi send 5 push notification after turn on Wi-Fi receive only one push notification. I'm read below answer but me did  not help. How are you resolve problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Referencing a couple of references:

**iOS:**

> Apple Push Notification service includes a Quality of Service (QoS)
>   component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts
>   to deliver a notification and the destination device is offline, APNs
>   stores the notification for a limited period of time and delivers it
>   when the device becomes available again. This component stores only
>   the most recent notification per device and per app. If a device is
>   offline, sending a notification request targeting that device causes
>   the previous request to be discarded. If a device remains offline for
>   a long time, all its stored notifications in APNs are discarded.

- **This component stores only the most recent notification per device and per app.**
- **If a device is offline, sending a notification request targeting that device causes the previous request to be discarded.**

This would mean that only one notification is preserved and that sending a new one replaced the old one. So I don't think it's possible.

[Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html)

**Android:**

> On Android and Web/JavaScript, you can specify the maximum lifespan of
>   a message. The value must be a duration from 0 to 2,419,200 seconds
>   (28 days), and it corresponds to the maximum period of time for which
>   FCM stores and attempts to deliver the message. Requests that don't
>   contain this field default to the maximum period of four weeks.

and

> Currently, time_to_live is not supported for notification messages on iOS

and

> If the device is not connected to GCM, the message will be stored
>   until a connection is established (again respecting the collapse key
>   rules). When a connection is established, GCM delivers all pending
>   messages to the device. If the device never gets connected again (for
>   instance, if it was factory reset), the message will eventually time
>   out and be discarded from GCM storage. The default timeout is 4 weeks,
>   unless the time_to_live flag is set.

and

> Finally, when GCM attempts to deliver a message to the device and the
>   application was uninstalled, GCM will discard that message right away
>   and invalidate the registration token. Future attempts to send a
>   message to that device will result in a NotRegistered error.

- **When a connection is established, GCM delivers all pending messages to the device.**
- **If the device never gets connected again (for instance, if it was factory reset), the message will eventually time out and be discarded from GCM storage.**
- **The default timeout is 4 weeks, unless the time_to_live flag is set.**
- **Finally, when GCM attempts to deliver a message to the device and the application was uninstalled, GCM will discard that message right away and invalidate the registration token.**

Meaning it should be receiving the pending messages. Unless the device is factory reset or uninstalled.

[About FCM Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

[Messaging Concepts and Options](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options) (although this is deprecated and now suggests to reference FCM messaging, linked above)

Comment: I tested push notifications for android devices when using "priority=normal" and they got lost even when the device was sleeping - meaning still turned on - and woken up 2 minutes after message was sent. Since I wanted "priority=high" my problem was solved, but this behavior is not what I expected.

Comment: I'm only getting the last one i send. I tried the collapse key and priority and nothing worked.

Comment: @CarlosSilva, that is the expected behavior according to the APNS docs.