# When you are on flight mode and exit from the Flight mode, i am receiving only the last FCM push notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am only receiving the last push notification(FCM) after exiting from the flight mode. However if my app is in foreground, I will get all the push notifications once i leave the flight mode . I have implemented FCM message type as notification message .

NOTE:
Can't Implement FCM message type as Data message due to the fact that only Notification message is accepted by APNS for my iOS counterpart .

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52524623/4659743

Comment: I have the same problem, and setting a collapse key didnt helped