# Firebase push notification is not working properly when device is offline

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implement a tap action on the notification and then i found out that when i am offline and triggering the notification. and when i am coming to online i am only receiving the last notification. and it is only happening in android

please help

I  have read lot of solution but did not found any proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522362/receive-all-the-push-notifications-when-devices-are-offline) then. Check notification's time to live first, and if you're sure that's not the cause, make sure you're using different notification ids for notifications, otherwise you'll replace the currently shown notification with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Answered a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74801324/20447561). This is working as intended as [notification messages are always collapsible](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages:%7E:text=Notification%20messages%20are%20always%20collapsible).