# some notifications are missing when devices are offline and got connected again using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging v1 (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send)

I have successfully implemented the notification in my android device and I already got the push notifications.

Problem is, when my device is not connected to internet for a while, and got connected again, all of my push notifications are missing, except the last one. (I tried to sent 5 notifications with different title and body, and only got the last one, the 4 older notifications are gone).

I've already founded this same issue on [Receive all the push notifications when devices are offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522362/receive-all-the-push-notifications-when-devices-are-offline)

but after looked at the answer, it seems the reality on my android is not as the expected answer: "When a connection is established, GCM delivers all pending messages to the device."

Since, it was 4 years ago, it might be not relevant in 2022.

I've tried some setup including set different value of **collapse_key**, **topic**, and **tag** , **ttl**, **high priority** but it was not solving the issue at all.
Hence, has someone found the solution regarding this ? We can focused on android device only (we're not using iOS device at all)

this is the android manifest I used

```
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
       android:value="default_channel" />
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
       android:resource="@drawable/ic_notif" />
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
       android:resource="@color/red" />
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing expiry time of notification from console?

Comment: yess, you mean ttl right? I've tried that as well

Comment: Can you share your manifest file? And try to send in test mode if you are not.

Comment: why? androidManifest.xml doesn't handle the notification logic, does it?

Comment: Not the logic but a service needs to be specified inside application tag for notifications.

Comment: ok, I've added my android manifest @FahadBinAsif

Comment: Yes please define your service in manifest as well. Follow this guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 1):

If you're using notification payload, this is working as intended. [Notification messages are always collapsible](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages:%7E:text=Notification%20messages%20are%20always%20collapsible) that's why only the last notification is received. You can try using data payload instead since it's non-collapsible by default.

Comment: How about for iOS?

Comment: [Same behavior](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364493) can also be expected with APNs.